# Laravel eloquent with pivot table

Tags: laravel

I have this table relationship:

[image]

I already made all the relationships in my models properly, but i don't know how to get the name from worktypes table

when i do

```
dd($shift->shift_workers);
```

i get this:

[image]

but i want also somehow to get the name from worktype table for each worker...

This should be done somehow withPivot() function or what?
So i could have something like this:

```
$foreach ($shift->shift_workers as $w => $worker)
    echo $worker->name;
```

but i don't know how to do this...anyone can help?

Comment: Can you also add your relationship methods and how you query `$shift` to your question?

Comment: I have solved this with `implode($worker->worktype->pluck('id')->toArray())` now i get the name, actually i get an id number but that is for my select box so get the name shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is obvious and logically right that the pivot table should be skipped so the result is achieved by:

```
$worker->worktypes->first()->name; // to get the name of the first work type
$worker->worktypes->pluck('name'); // to get all names as an array
```

To achieve this result, follow [Laravel's naming convention](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) and set up model relationsips right.

1. Rename your `worker_worktype_pivot` table to `worker_worktype`
2. Set up the relationship in the `Worker` model:

`

```
class Worker extends Model {
    ...
    public function workTypes()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(WorkType::class);
    }
}
```

Comment: If i don't use pivot table...shouldn't workTypes relation in my worker model be belongsTo() instead of belongsToMany() as you specified?

Comment: Is it `belongsTo`? Your screenshot shows that it's `belongsToMany` (1 → ∞). There wouldn't be a need to have a pivot table if it was `belongsTo`

Comment: What I did after your comment is that I deleted my pivot table and connected workers directly to worktypes, added the foreign key in workers ( worktypes I'd ) and now I don't have a pivot table at all...I don't have time now but I will be back tonight probably but I want to solve this through